# Не работает удаление в hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

```
@Override
public void updateCompetence(Long id, CompetenceInDTO competenceInDTO) {

    Competence competence = findCompetenceById(id);
    if (competenceInDTO.getSubcompetences().size() < competence.getSubcompetences().size()) {
        subcompetenceRepository.delete(id);

        rewrite(competenceInDTO, id);
    }}
```

Не работает subcompetenceRepository.delete(id). Просто заходит в него, отрабатывает, и в следующей строке на выходе размер остается тот же. 
Если вынести delete из if, то он отработает. Так же если в if(true) удаление проходит успешно. Никаких exception нет. В debug hibernate тоже нет запроса в базу

Comment: Запроса и не будет, у Вас сущность в кеше болтается. А зачем Вам, позвольте поинтересоваться удалять а потом заного перезаписывать изменненную сущноть? Не проще ли одной операцией save обойтись?

Comment: @GenCloud ну мне может поступить отредактированный лист объектов, размером меньше, чем в базе. И я подумал, что если их меньше, то я удалю разность между количеством объектов у меня и поступившей и перезапишу оставшиеся

Comment: @GenCloud А что мне надо исправить чтоб сущность не болталась в кэше?